# Prove for all positive integers n that $7^{4n} −1$ is a multiple of $15$. You may not use proof by induction.

Tags: proof-writing

I factored this out to be $(7^n-1)(7^n+1)(7^{2n}+1)$, and I know I need to prove that I can always factor out a 3 and a 5, but I have no idea how to get there, especially without induction. My professor said I can use the rule of three consecutive integers (how one of them will always be a multiple of 3) to get started, but that doesn't look to be possible here.

Comment: I suppose $7^{4n}-1=2401^n-1=(2401-1)(2401^{n-1}+2401^{n-2}+\cdots+2401+1)$, but **really** can you prove $x^n-1=(x-1)(x^{n-1}+\cdots+1)$ "without induction"?

Comment: I could prove it by induction, but I'm trying to get full credit on this assignment

Comment: The site has a strict policy against homework problems

Answer (score 3):

$$(7^{4})^n-1=(2401)^n-1=(2401-1)P(n)=2400 P_{n-1}(2401)$$ which is divisible by 15. Here $P_{n-1}(2401)$ is a polynomial of degree $n-1$: $1+(2301)+(2401)^2+....+(2401)^{n-1}$ - an integer.

Comment: a good answer...

Comment: What is P(n), here?

Comment: @Arjun Rana Actually this is a polynomial of  (2401) of degree $n-1$ like : 1+(2301)+(2401)^2+....+(2401)^{n-1}$ which is a whole number..Please  see the edit.

Comment: Thank you for clarification

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you are allowed to use or know modular arithmetic, but we know that $7^4=2401$ which has a remainder of $1$ when divided by $15$. Then $7^{4n}-1= (7^4)^n-1=(2401)^n-1$ has remainder $1^n-1=1-1=0$ when divided by $15$; that is, $7^{4n}-1$ is divisible by $15$. In modular arithmetic language, this is because
$$
7^{4n}-1 \equiv (2401)^n-1 \equiv 1^n-1 \equiv 0 \mod 15
$$

Answer (score 1):

A simple and direct way is using the binomial formula in the form

- ($\star$): $(ak+b)^m = const\cdot k + b^m$

So, you get

- Divisibility by $3$:
  $$7^{4n}-1 = \underbrace{(2\cdot 3 + 1)^{4n}}_{\stackrel{(\star)}{=}3K+1} - 1 = 3K$$
- Divisibility by $5$:
  $$7^{4n}-1 = \underbrace{(50 - 1)^{2n}}_{\stackrel{(\star)}{=}5L+1} - 1 = 5L$$